# php Вызов родительского конструктора при отсутствии

Tags: php, ооп, множественное-наследование

Есть такой код

```
<?php

class C {

}

class B {
    public function __construct() {
        return new C();
    }
}

class A extends B {

}

var_dump(new A());
```

Он выводит следующее: `object(A)#1 (0) {}`, что подразумевает что я получаю экземпляр класса `A`.

Есть ли возможность таким способом получать экземпляр класса `C`?

Comment: в php нет множественного наследования, но есть [traits](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.oop5.traits.php)

Comment: вы создаете объект А, как вы надеетесь при этом получить С?

Comment: Интересно, а вам зачем?

Answer (score 3):

Получить значение из метода `__construct()` можно если вызвать его напрямую.
(Если в конструктор передаются параметры, то при вызове функции так же необходимо их передать.)

```
class C {
}

class B {
    public function __construct() {
        return new C();
    }
}

class A extends B {
}

$test = new A();
var_dump($test->__construct());
```

Но так делать не рекомендуется.

Answer (score 3):

Задача конструктора в инициализации первоначальных значений свойств объекта, выполнении инициализирующих операций.

Не надо его использовать для возврата значений, даже если есть такая возможность. 
Если вы пытаетесь что-то вернуть из конструктора, значит вы что-то делаете неправильно, и не нужно искать обходные пути, чтобы это сделать через конструктор.

**Конструктор и деструктор, в отличии от обычных методов, никогда не должен возвращать значение**